# Nesting fetch requests

Tags: swift, core-data, relationship, nspredicate

In my project, I have two entities: `personEntity` & `municipalEntity`.  These have a many-to-many inverse relationship with each other.  I execute a `NSFetchRequest` on `personEntity` to get a person's details:

```
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context = appDelegate.managedObjectContext
    let personRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "personEntity")
    let personPred = NSPredicate(format: "surname = %@", "Smith")
    personRequest.predicate = personPred
    do {
        let personsList = try context.executeFetchRequest(personRequest)
        // this all clear enough up to this point
```

At this point, I try to nest a second, predicated `FetchRequest` within the first.  This request should search `municipalEntity` in its `peopleInMunicipality` relationship property, for the objects from `personsList`.

```
        for selectedPeople in personsList {
            let municipalRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "municipalEntity")
            let municipalPred = NSPredicate(format: "peopleInMunicipality = %@", selectedPeople)
            municipalRequest.predicate = municipalPred
            do {
                let municipalitiesWithResidentsCalledSmithList = try context.executeFetchRequest(municipalRequest)
```

And bang... the compiler complains and suggests I need to change two things in the line defining the second predicate.  It suggests instead...

```
            let municipalPred = NSPredicate(format: "peopleInMunicipality = %@", argumentArray: selectedPerson as? [AnyOject])
```

The compiler is now happy but when I run the code, it crashes with an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error on the suggested `argumentArray:` code section.
Any idea how I can fix this?

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but if you have many-to-many relationships there is a attribute in each entity referring to the other entity. After you have filtered the people you can retrieve the associated `municipalEntity` items from the mentioned attribute of each person.

Comment: That's pretty much what I'm trying to do. If an entity has an attribute, I can run a predicate (like in the first loop).  If the property is a relationship though, the same approach should also apply.  I'm missing the syntax to compare an object in an entity's relationship with the reference object. "Object =%@" is possibly the wrong approach.

Comment: To be clear: an entity has properties. A property can be an attribute or a relationship. vadian says attribute and means relationship.

Comment: That's how I'd read Vadian's comment too.

Comment: Right, I mixed up the terminology, I mean relationship

Answer (score 1, accepted):

vadian is right. You don't need the second fetch request. If the reverse relationship of `peopleInMunicipality` is called `municipalities`, the municipalities of `selectedPeople` is `selectedPeople.municipalities`.

If you really want to execute a second fetch request, the predicate format would be `peopleInMunicipality CONTAINS %@`.

Comment: Ok.  I hadn't tried that yet.  I found how to get my code to work though.  The line defining the nested predicate that works is:... let municipalPred = NSPredicate(format: "peopleInMunicipality = %@", selectedPeople as! NSManagedObject)

Comment: Are you sure `peopleInMunicipality` is a to-many relationship?

Answer (score 0):

Since I cannot post comment. You can try SubQuery on MunicipalEntity like this:

```
     NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SUBQUERY(peopleInMunicipality, $person, $person.surname == %@).@count > 0", @"Smith"];
```

Use this Predicate on Municipal Entity

Comment: Or simply without a subquery `ANY peopleInMunicipality.surname  = %@`